# Sound activated recording in Julia

Tags: audio, triggers, julia, signal-processing

I'm recording audio with Julia and want to be able to trigger a 5 second recording after the audio signal exceeds a certain volume. This is my record script so far:

```
using PortAudio, SampledSignals, LibSndFile, FileIO, Dates

stream = PortAudioStream("HDA Intel PCH: ALC285 Analog (hw:0,0)")

buf = read(stream, 5s)

close(stream)

save(string("recording_", Dates.format(now(), "yyyymmdd_HHMMSS"), ".wav"), buf, Fs = 48000)
```

I'm new to Julia and signal processing in general. How can I tell this only to start recording once the audio exceeds a specified volume threshold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test the sound you capture for average amplitude and act on that.  Save if loud enough, otherwise rinse and repeat.

```
using PortAudio, SampledSignals, LibSndFile, FileIO

const hassound = 10   # choose this to fit

suprathreshold(buf, thresh = hassound) = norm(buf) / sqrt(length(buf)) > thresh  # power over threshold
    
stream = PortAudioStream("HDA Intel PCH: ALC285 Analog (hw:0,0)")

while true
    buf = read(stream, 5s)
    close(stream)
    if suprathreshold(buf)
        save("recording.wav", buf, Fs = 48000) # should really append here maybe???
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill, I've made a couple of edits and it works great

Comment: Your comment about appending - what do you mean?

Comment: To avoid overwriting recording.wav if that is important, you could append the write to the file with WAV.wavappend(), or you could change the file name each time data is written.